# require() not defined in Electron HTML page

Tags: javascript, node.js, webview, electron

I'm currently unable to load Electron modules in Javascript files outside of the main.js file.

I'm trying to use:

`const electron = require('electron');`

`const ipcRenderer = electron.ipcRenderer;`

in a file called settings.js.

I have the correct NPM modules installed (eletron-prebuilt).

The settings page is loaded in a webview like so:

`<webview id="settings" src="./settings.html"></webview>`

and the settings.js included like:

`<script type='text/javascript' src='./resources/js/settings.js'></script>`

Running out of ideas here, but I wonder if it's some kind of scoping issue?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're loading it in a webview, which doesn't support [nodeintegration](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#nodeintegration) by default.

Add the `nodeintegration` attribute to your webivew.

```
<webview id="settings" src="./settings.html" nodeintegration></webview>
```