# Require is not defined on electron with cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, cypress

I'm trying to implement cypress in my electron app, but on first line of code which is `cy.visit('index.html')` it throws `require is not defined`

My index.html contains this inside `<script>` tag. Webpack preprocessing didn't make sense.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key === "I") { // для возможности открытия в релизных версиях
        let remote = require("electron").remote;
        remote.getCurrentWindow().toggleDevTools();
    }
});
// You can also require other files to run in this process
let render = require('./out/App').render;
render('id1');
```

Comment: I can't comment ! [Take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: Don't know much about `cypress`, but yeah, make sure your node integration is turned on. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36859984/require-not-defined-in-electron-html-page).

Comment: @MabroukiFakhri didnt do a thing. Where should I add it? On index.html? If yes, it will still (and it does, actually) throw about require.